# How can I get the last update date for a Github file using Octokit gem?

Tags: ruby, octokit

I am using [Octokit](https://rubygems.org/gems/octokit) gem to access the contents of a file with the following command:

```
Octokit.contents("user/reponame", path: 'path/to/file.md')
```

which works well to get the contents. The question that I have is how do I get the last update date and time stamp of that file?

Comment: Have you figure out an answer to your question? I'm looking for something similar as well.